# Drupal 8 get index on a loop on twig

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I need to design the first position of an array with some style and the other 4 articles with another style.

Is there a way to get the index in a twig loop?

I would like something like that :

```
<div{{ content_attributes }}>

<div class="title">
    {{ label }}
</div>
<div class="body">
    {{ content.body }}
</div>
<div class="link">
    {{ url }}
</div>
<div class="image">
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    <img width="100" height="100" src="{{ content.field_image }}">
    {% else %}
        <img width="100" height="100" src="default.png">
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Loop index? the html for the image field has already been generated by the field template (I think)

Comment: If you are referring to a list of articles, say in a view,  then it is the view.html.twig that contains the loop. 

Is this for the node page, using the default or full content view mode?

Comment: i use the teaser mode

Comment: But i can take the full content if you have a solution. i just want to design only the first article and the other 4 articles with an other design.

Comment: The loop index is in a for sequence. For example in the views-view-unformatted.html.twig. So the point is that you want an other image in only the first article?

Comment: Yes Ann, i don't need the same size for the first image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first value of an array on twig, you can simply use the `[0]` index.

```
    //dump the value of the first position of the array
    {{ dump(array[0]) }}
```

and to get the values of the array in a for loop starting from the second position you can use:

```
{% for key in array|keys %}
    {% set s_key = key + 1 %}
    //dump the value of the array starting from the second position...
    {{ dump(array[s_key].title) }}
{% endfor %}
```